# Javascript shorthand loading time

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I was playing around so I ran into a JS shorthands. I know they, of course, do not change code however do they lower loading time since there is less data?

Testing codes such as one below in Chrome DOM inspector did not give me an answer (probably because they are one-line codes so it does not make any difference).

```
if (x == 0) {x=1} else {x=2}
x == 0 ? x = 1 : x = 2;
```

Comment: What kind of answer were you expecting the DOM inspector to show?

Comment: You can shorten it to `x = x == 0 ? 1 : 2`

Comment: It comes with network inspector, which displays loading time of external files..

Comment: You would need hundreds or thousands of shorthands like this to make a noticeable difference in loading time.

Comment: Just use a Javascript minifier, don't worry about how you code it yourself.

Comment: If you load the same file multiple times, the loading times will differ, probably by more than the effects of these little shorthands. You need to do it hundreds of times and average them to get useful statistics.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to optimize the speed with which your page loads by minimizing the size of your JS payload, there are lots of tools that will automatically rebuild your files into a single bundle that is compressed (i.e., all unnecessary whitespace removed, variables/functions renamed to shorter lengths, etc.). When it comes to writing code, you should *always* value readability first.

Write code that other people can easily understand. Then, when you're ready to deploy, look into a tool like [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), which will enable you to take code like this:

```
function square(numToSquare) {
    var squareProduct = numToSquare * numToSquare;

    return squareProduct;
}

square(15);
```

..and turn it into this:

```
function square(r){return r*r}square(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

The less characters and whitespace in a file, the lower the download size of said scripts is.

Readability is also a matter of utmost importance though, and ternary operators can be confusing in certain scenarios.

I would recommend that for those cases where you expect your codebase to increase to a certain extend over time, you stick to more readable constructs and use a minification/uglification process to lower file size.